# Close icon is not displaying correctly in the notification bar

Tags: bug, design, notifications

When we are editing a post, if some other user is edited the same post or it is closed as duplicate we are receiving a notification in the top of the page with the orange color background. Like:

> This question has been closed - no more answers will be accepted.

In the notification, instead of the close **x** icon, there is a different image is displaying.

[image: Close button]

Looks like from the [sprites.png](https://meta.stackexchange.com/content/Sites/stackexchangemeta/img/sprites.png?v=edcc02aec905), the close button position is not taking correctly, so the partial part of the Stack Exchange image is displaying instead of the close button.

I have recorded as GIF for the same.

[image: GIF for the same]

**Update:**

If remove the `background-image: url("img/sprites.png?v=edcc02aec905") !important;` from the `span.notify-close`, the close icon is displaying correctly.

**GIF for the same:**

[image: Close icon displaying correctly]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today while editing a post, I get the notification bar again.

Now the close button is displaying correctly, looks like the issue has been fixed.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Notification bar - Close button icon]