# Can anyone explain the meaning of this icon?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, notification-bar

I am preparing an answer for a question today and then the post is closed as dupe. So, I saw the yellow banner at the top(as usual) but with a special kind of icon.

[image]

If you want a close look

[image]

It is clear that the button is there to close the banner (the tooltip also states that).

I expect a close icon **X** or something similar. But this thing doesn't make sense.

Please change it.

> Chrome/61.0.3163.100 on windows 10

**Update**

This is how it looks in Stack Overflow

[image]

Comment: Don't be silly. That clearly is an ... an ... just pretend it is an X, Ok? Just like we have to pretend certain icons depict a review queue ...

Comment: Well, it's not part of the [sprites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/content/Sites/stackexchangemeta/img/sprites.svg?v=bb0497e70aa3)...

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think it is some custom svg like the ones they are using for top bar icons

Comment: Hard to believe they'll spend time creating special SVG for something so rarely used. But... who knows. When you next see it, inspect the element and we'll know for sure.

Comment: To me: It looks like a  piece of the Stack Exchange logo. Not sure.

Comment: @HenryWHHackv2.1 for me too but can't confirm

Comment: @ShadowWizard if you dupehammer this one to some other question, I can test it now

Comment: Nah, better not use the hammer for such tests. Best is wait for off topic question here to appear, and wait until it's closed.

Comment: Completely unrelated to the problem, but please use PNG for screenshots. At least I assume you're not using a 256-color screen any more, so saving a screenshot as a GIF is unavoidably lossy. Thanks. :)

Comment: "this question has sailed away from [answerers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281787/165773)"

Comment: Confirmed. `StackExchange.notify.show("Consider yourself notified", 42)` in the console to reproduce.

Comment: @balpha I think it is the top left corner of MSE logo as said by Henry

Comment: Fun fact, this has been broken since early 2015.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek [Someone has.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292804/350861) So much for "can no longer be reproduced"...

Comment: The answer by Arulkumar made them vote to close it as no repro. as I said in this question, it happens only in MSE. but in that answer, Arul kumar tested in SO.
/cc @InquisitiveLurker

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Fixed in the next build, thanks.

This has been broken for over two and a half years – the close button had the sprite sheet as its background image (a leftover from long ago), but no `background-position` set because it wasn't actually meant to be sprited anymore.

Which means that the "×" always had the top-left corner of the sprite sheet in the background. The sprite sheet is different per-site, and on most sites, there's nothing in the top left corner – but on some, as you found, there is.