# Can we please remove the weird looking orange banner that appears when a new answer is posted while I view a question?

Tags: discussion, design, notifications

I don't know when this came to be, or if this is the reason we can't have nice things like [disabled stickyness on the topbar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368973/we-ve-removed-the-option-to-disable-the-fixed-top-bar) but it looks godawfull. What was wrong with the old pop-up above the answers?

[image]

Comment: The orange banner is not the new one, and it is not due to the topbar stickiness disabled change. It is available for a long time, reference: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296520/312043

Comment: @Arulkumar For me this was the first time I've seen it in years. So there must be something going on.

Comment: Yes, it's been here for a long time. Maybe the new thing is using it to notify about new answers?

Comment: Yes, you can remove the banner by clicking the small "x" at its right end.

Comment: Thanks for stating the obvious @ThomasMarkov. I just don't want it to pop-up at all. It's awfully intrusive with its orange colour that has no place here on MSE. The old style was way better.

Comment: I see it pretty consistently. I don't think there's any recent changes that caused you to see it, just chance.

Comment: @Catija I never see it, there is always just a banner right above the other answers. Could be because this page was re-loaded after restarting the computer though. I don't do much Windows anymore lately, but on MAC I've never seen it. (Both use FF as browser)

Comment: Hmmm... Maybe the one I'm thinking about is for something else. I think we use this sort of banner for a few different things... new answers, question closed, edit to post while editing... etc.

Comment: @Catija I've seen it for other things but I don't think I've ever seen it for new answers. [This](https://i.imgur.com/BhcTMQk.png) is what I _still_ see when a new answer is posted.

Comment: @41686d6564 That's exactly what I'm used to seeing!

Comment: I think I solved the mystery. The orange banner for new answers most likely only appears _while you're typing an answer_. I just got the same banner in your screenshot while I was typing an answer and it reminded me that this isn't actually new either. CC: @Catija